# No route matches [POST] "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having some trouble trying to submit an AJAX request to a separate controller in my view.

My form for the AJAX request looks like this:
I've also tried `sites_search_results_index_path` which my routes file says is the proper route.

View:

```
<div class="pull-left col-md-5">
  <%= form_tag url: sites_search_results, remote: true do %>
    <div class="input-group">
      <%= content_tag :span, class: "input-group-btn" do %>

        <%= button_tag type: "button", class: "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle", data: { toggle: "dropdown" } do %>
          <%= content_tag :span, "", class: "caret" %>
        <% end %>

        <%= content_tag :ul, class: "dropdown-menu" do %>
          <li class="btn btn-default">Domain</li>
          <li class="btn btn-default">CLW</li>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>

      <%= hidden_field_tag "search_by", "Domain" %>
      <%= content_tag :span, class: "input-group-addon", id: "search_view" do %>
        Filter
      <% end %>

      <%= text_field_tag "search_for", "", :class => "form-control" %>
      <%= content_tag :span, class: "input-group-btn" do %>
        <%= button_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-default" %>
      <% end %>

    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
class SitesSearchResultsController < ApplicationController

  def index

    field = "Domain"

    @results = Domain.where()

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js # do ajax action
    end
  end

end
```

Routes:

```
resource :sites_search_results do
  post 'index'
end
# also tried with no result:
#post "sites_search_results/index"
```

`rake routes` has:

```
sites_search_results POST   /sites_search_results/index(.:format)            sites_search_results#index
                     POST   /sites_search_results(.:format)                  sites_search_results#create
```

The result of this is:

```
undefined local variable or method `sites_search_results'
```

Any idea what would cause this? I've seen other people have this problem but I have the root path set up already to go to the status page. And I don't see anything that would be attempting to post to root. Let me know if anything else is needed to help. And thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show us the relevant lines out of `rake routes` and the relevant lines on your logs when you are shown this error?

Comment: @Leito just added it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the form_tag url should be:

```
<%= form_tag url: sites_search_results_path, remote: true do %>
```

Or

```
<%= form_tag url: sites_search_results_url, remote: true do %>
```

Run 'rake routes' from the command line and it see if you have 'sites_search_results' or 'sites_search_results_index'. I am guessing the former.

Also, try changing your route definition from:

```
resource :sites_search_results do
  post 'index'
end
```

To simply,

```
post 'sites_search_results' => sites_search_results#index
```

Finally, do you need to use a POST? Index methods are usually GETs in which case you'd that post to a get.

Comment: When I ran it from command line I got:

`sites_search_results POST   /sites_search_results/index(.:format)            sites_search_results#index`  
                                 `POST   /sites_search_results(.:format)                  sites_search_results#create`  

And then when I load the page it says:  

undefined local variable or method `sites_search_results'  
after updating the url

Comment: It needs to be 'sites_search_results_path', not 'sites_search_results'.

Comment: Then I'm back to `No route matches [POST] "/"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the method inside your form_tag like this :-

```
<%= form_tag url: sites_search_results,:method=>'post', remote: true do %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same problem still. `No route matches [POST] "/"` Any other idea why that might be?